# Javascript: Local and Global variable processing order

Tags: javascript

I am confused with the output of the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
           <script>
            var num1 = 10;
            function checkScope(){
                var num2 = 20;
                console.log('Inside: Num1 is '+num1);
                console.log('Inside: Num2 is '+num2);
            }
                console.log('Outside:Num1 is '+num1);
                console.log('Outside:Num2 is '+num2);
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload='checkScope();'>
        <h3>Scopes in JavaScript</h3>
        </body >
</html>
```

Output to this code is:

```
Outside:Num1 is 10
Uncaught ReferenceError: num2 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:9:36
    at submitTryit (tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_datatypes_addstring:600)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_datatypes_addstring:460)
Inside: Num1 is 10
Inside: Num2 is 20
```

Now my query is, Why Outside:Num1 and Outside:Num2 is coming first in the console. Should it not be in the order of, first the Inside:Num1 and Num2 set and THEN Outside Num1 and Num2?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your `checkScope` only runs when the body sees the `load` event, which occurs a while after the `<script>` tag (and its `console.log('Outside:Num1 is '+num1);`) has finished

Comment: You are missing the fact that function is declared and code after it runs. It does not sit around waiting, if it did, we would not be able to code a lot of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just understand like this.

**`onload`** » `All things loaded`

**`All things loaded`** » `Head loaded` + `Body loaded`

> **Note:** Code always execute from top to bottom, if any function encounters in between then it will be read but not triggered, so code inside it executes once we trigger it.

#### `Head loaded`

1. `<script>` will load and all things inside this will execute one by one, `function checkScope(){}` will be read but will not be triggered as it is will be triggered once **All things loaded (onload)** which is next.
2. `console.log()`s are not a part of any function so these will be executed immediately.

#### `Body loaded`

- `<h3>` will be placed in DOM.

#### All things loaded (onload) » `Head loaded` + `Body loaded`

- So `onload='checkScope();'` will work now, and code inside it will be executed.

I hope, this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. Now I understand it correctly.

Comment: Brilliant, Good luck.